# Route::controllers - Method [index] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I am running `PHP 7.0.25` and `Laravel Framework 5.5.25`.

I would like to use the [laravel datatables package](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master) and followed the [quickstart guide](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/) and have exactly the same `controller` and `view`.

However, when running my application I get the following error:

```
BadMethodCallException thrown with message "Method [index] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\DatatablesController]."

Stacktrace:
#51 BadMethodCallException in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:68
#50 Illuminate\Routing\Controller:__call in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
#49 call_user_func_array in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
#48 Illuminate\Routing\Controller:callAction in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:45
#47 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:dispatch in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:212
#46 Illuminate\Routing\Route:runController in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:169
#45 Illuminate\Routing\Route:run in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:658
#44 Illuminate\Routing\Router:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
#43 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:41
#42 Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#41 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#40 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:67
#39 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#38 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#37 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php:49
#36 Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#35 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#34 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:63
#33 Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#32 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#31 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37
#30 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#29 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#28 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:59
#27 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#26 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#25 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:102
#24 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:660
#23 Illuminate\Routing\Router:runRouteWithinStack in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:635
#22 Illuminate\Routing\Router:runRoute in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:601
#21 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:590
#20 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:176
#19 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
#18 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php:56
#17 Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#16 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#15 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:30
#14 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#13 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#12 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:30
#11 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#10 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27
#8 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#7 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#6 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:46
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:149
#4 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#3 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:102
#2 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:151
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:sendRequestThroughRouter in /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:116
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:handle in /home/ubuntu/workspace/public/index.php:55
```

I expect that this error is coming from my route configuration, which I changed to `Route::resource` instead, as mentioned in the [quickstart guide](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/), of the deprecated - since laravel 5.3 - `Route::controllers`:

```
Route::resource('datatables', 'DatatablesController', [
    'anyData'  => 'datatables.data',
    'getIndex' => 'datatables',
]);
```

Any suggestions how to write the route properly?

PS.: I already used `composer dumpautoload`, `composer install` & `composer update` and it does not change the error

**UPDATE**

My current Controller looks like the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;

class DatatablesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Displays datatables front end view
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return view('datatables.index');
    }

    /**
     * Process datatables ajax request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function anyData()
    {
        return Datatables::of(User::query())->make(true);
    }
}
```

My view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="users-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Created At</th>
                <th>Updated At</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
@stop

@push('scripts')
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('datatables.data') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
            { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
@endpush
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a resource controller using artisan

```
php artisan make:controller DatatablesController --resource
```

The create controller will have the methods needed by your resource route

[more info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers)

Note: the 3th param(the array) is not valid

Comment: Thx for your reply! I generated the resource controller. How, should the correct controller and the route look like? I kindly ask you for sample code.

Comment: the controller will look like the generated controller, in the route collection you should remove the 3th param, i don't know what you are trying to do there

Comment: Please see above my update of my current controller. I basically want to load the index page and with the function `anyData` I load the axjax request.

Comment: if you have custom method you need a custom route

Comment: `Route::get('datatables/data', 'DatatablesController@getIndex')->name('datatables.data')`

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.php, Laravel search a controller (in your case, `DatatablesController`) and a method to execute in this controller like `DatatablesController@methodToExecute`. 
By default, Laravel try to execute the method `index`. Like [@madalinivascu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906356/madalinivascu) wrote, this controller needs to exists.