# Laravel : Method [index] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\admin\PostsController]

Tags: php, laravel

This answer doesn't solve my problem  [Route::controllers - Method [index] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767018/routecontrollers-method-index-does-not-exist-on-app-http-controllers)

In web.php

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('post', 'admin\PostsController');
});
```

in app/Http/Controllers/admin

I have PostsController.php

which contains

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use App\Model\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $posts = \App\Post::all();
        return view('admin.posts',['posts'=>$posts]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $post = new Post;

        $post->content = $request->input('descr');

        $post->save();
    }
```

When I go to this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/post

I get the following error

> BadMethodCallException Method [index] does not exist on
>   [App\Http\Controllers\admin\PostsController].

```
call_user_func_array
…
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php 56 

 public function callAction($method, $parameters)
    {
        print_r($this);
        echo $method;die();
        return call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $parameters);
    }
```

//prints

```
App\Http\Controllers\admin\PostsController Object ( [middleware:protected] => Array ( ) ) index
```

php artisan prints the following

```
php artisan route:list 

|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/post             | post.index   | App\Http\Controllers\admin\PostsController@index   | web
```

Comment: Try to access `posts`.

Comment: @MASh  Dou want me to try http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/posts instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/post I get page not found error

Comment: yes. try this one.

Comment: @MASh I get page not found error

Comment: Rewrite this line from `Route::resource('post', 'admin\PostsController');` to `Route::resource('posts', 'admin\PostsController');` And then try to access `admin/posts`

Comment: @MASh same problem

Comment: Then there is something. Write a route: `Route:get('posts','admin\PostsController@index'); and now try to access to `admin/posts`.

Comment: Try, removing the prefix in the route and from the URL too, and check if you can access that index method anyway.

Comment: Looks fine, what version of Laravel are you using? You're also missing a closing bracket in your `PostsController`, but that's probably a copy/paste error

Comment: @kerbholz I am using 5.5.34

Comment: why downvote. downvoter please tell me the reason

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have **Ambiguous class** in your controllers, that means you may have same class name in different controllers. To solve that problem, run these commands

```
 1. composer update 
 2. composer dumpautoload
 3. php artisan config:cache
 4. php artisan view:clear
```

Make sure that **composer update** runs successfully without errors. If errors are mentioned in the console, correct all of them where they occur in your codebase.

Comment: Thanks chap! U made my day, apparently, i spent a few hrs debugging what was wrong with my routes and controller, finally caught that i had renamed a controller to `ControllerOld` but the `Controller` class name still existed in the old controller hence the `Controller` was conficting with class name defined in old controller hence this exception! Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Using laravel version 5.4 , i ran this commands

`php artisan make:controller admin/PostsController --resource`

in web.php routes file added this

`Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('post', 'admin\PostsController');
});`

controller  file

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
  public function index()
  {
    echo "call to index";
  }
  ........
   other functions

}
```

works fine for me

[image]